# I don't get the result of my promise despite using await

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, request

My function looks like this:

```
async function getPlaceForecast(lat, long) {
//var response;
var day5forecast = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=' + apikey;
try {
    const request = new Request(tmp2, {
        method: 'get'
    })
    let response = await fetch(request)
        .then(value => {
            console.log("than", value.json());
            return value//.json();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
catch{

}
//return response;
```

}

This is the result:

```
'than', { _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }
```

And this is the result without using .json() :

```
'than', { type: 'default',
status: 200,
ok: true,
   statusText: undefined,
  headers:
   { map:
     { 'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST',
       'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'x-cache-key': '/data/2.5/forecast?lat=28.35&lon=-14.05',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
       'content-length': '14383',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         server: 'openresty' } },
  url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=28.349414&lon=-14.046311&appid=<mykey>',
  _bodyInit:
    { _data:
     { size: 14383,
       offset: 0,
   blobId: '2dbf82c5-5d28-47db-9034-7f239bf8290a' } },
  _bodyBlob:
   { _data:
      { size: 14383,
       offset: 0,
        blobId: '2dbf82c5-5d28-47db-9034-7f239bf8290a' } } }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where is the url variable “day5forecast” used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging the promise returned by `json()`, not the promise's fulfillment value.

Here's how you'd do that function:

```
async function getPlaceForecast(lat, long) {
    const day5forecast = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=' + apikey;

    const request = new Request(tmp2, {
//                              ^^^^−−−−−−−−− Should this be `day5forecast` ??
//                                           `day5forecast` isn't used otherwise...
        method: 'get'
    })
    let response = await fetch(request);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

Note I've removed the `try`/`catch`es. Leave it for the caller to handle, so they know whether `getPlaceForecast` succeeded or failed.

You may be wondering about the lack of `await` at the end (`return response.json();`). You don't need it, because an `async` function always returns a promise. `return response.json();` resolves the `async` function's promise to the promise returned by `json()` (so it will be fulfilled or rejected based on what happens to the promise from `json()`). You *can* have `await` there (`return await response.json();`) and it's harmless,¹ but you don't need it.

---

¹ Specifically: A) It's completely harmless in a modern browser due to a change in ES2019; prior to that change in theory the overall fulfillment/rejection was delayed by one extra async "tick" (and that would still happen if the promise being returned weren't a native promise); B) It's *mostly* harmless even with that extra tick. :-)